# How To Iterate Over Array of URLs and Waiting for Response Before Moving To Next

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, async-await

I have a list of 900+ urls which I want to fetch for a daily cron job and I'm using Express.js.  I checked online for a way to do this and [ran across this jsinclair page](https://jrsinclair.com/articles/2019/how-to-run-async-js-in-parallel-or-sequential/), so I tried to implement that but so far didn't work.
Suppose this is my list:

```
let arrayOfAsyncTasks = [
    {task: 'fetch', url: 'http://thatapi.com/api1/thing'},
    {task: 'wait', duration: 60000 },
    {task: 'fetch', url: 'http://thatapi.com/api2/thing'},
    {task: 'wait', duration: 60000 },
    ...
]
```

What I have tried to do is use `Array.reduce` to force the iteration to adhere to a 60 second delay before beginning to fetch the next url, like so:

```
const starterPromise = Promise.resolve(null);
const log = result => console.log(result);

arrayOfAsyncTasks.reduce(
    (p, spec) => p.then(() => {
        runTask(spec)
        .then(result => {
            console.log(`Inside reduce function after runTask! result: `, result)
            log(result)
        })
     })
     .catch(err => console.log(`err: `, err) ),
     starterPromise
    );
```

and here are the helper functions:

```
function asyncTimeout(delay) {
    console.log(`inside asyncTimeout! delay: `, delay);
    return (new Promise(resolve => {setTimeout(() => resolve(delay), delay)}))
        .then(d => `Waited ${d} seconds`);
}

function asyncFetch(url) {
    console.log(`inside asyncFetch!  url: `, url);
    scrapeEbayCategory(url)
        .then(response => (response.json()))
        .then(text => `Fetched ${url}, and got back ${text}` );
}

function runTask(spec) {
    return (spec.task === 'wait')
    ? asyncTimeout(spec.duration)
    : asyncFetch(spec.url);
}
```

The result was that it moved way too fast to the next item and then in console it showed multiple console logs of the delay completing:

```
Waited 60000 seconds
Inside reduce function after runTask! result:  Waited 60000 seconds
Waited 60000 seconds
Inside reduce function after runTask! result:  Waited 60000 seconds
Waited 60000 seconds
Inside reduce function after runTask! result:  Waited 60000 seconds
Waited 60000 seconds
Inside reduce function after runTask! result:  Waited 60000 seconds
Waited 60000 seconds
Inside reduce function after runTask! result:  Waited 60000 seconds
Waited 60000 seconds
Inside reduce function after runTask! result:  Waited 60000 seconds
Waited 60000 seconds
Inside reduce function after runTask! result:  Waited 60000 seconds
Waited 60000 seconds
Inside reduce function after runTask! result:  Waited 60000 seconds
...
```

What I want the result to be is it waits for the fetch for one item to complete before moving to fetch the next item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems overly complicated.

Id rewrite it to loop over the array and based upon `task`, do fetch or wait, in async/await

```js
//
const sleep = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

let arrayOfAsyncTasks = [{
    task: 'fetch',
    url: 'http://thatapi.com/api1/thing'
  },
  {
    task: 'wait',
    duration: 60000
  },
  {
    task: 'fetch',
    url: 'http://thatapi.com/api2/thing'
  },
  {
    task: 'wait',
    duration: 60000
  }
]

;(async() => {

  for (let task of arrayOfAsyncTasks) {
    console.log('running', task)
    if (task.task === 'wait') {
      await sleep(task.duration)
    }

    if (task.task === 'fetch') {
      try {
        // await fetch(task.url)....
      } catch (e) {}
    }
  }
})()
```

Comment: WHY does this work?  Thank you.  I just tested it and it is finally sequentially doing this task.

Comment: is just hanging on the promise, its much like your code but just async/await and no debug. your code is just failing because you're not returning promises from the many .then's and awaiting on all of them. i.e callback hell. glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
handleTask = async function(task) {
  if (task.task === 'fetch') {
    // make API call here
    return APICALL(task.url)
  } else if (task.task === 'wait') {
    // sleep here
    await sleep(task.duration)
  }
}

let arrayOfAsyncTasks = [
    {task: 'fetch', url: 'http://thatapi.com/api1/thing'},
    {task: 'wait', duration: 60000 },
    {task: 'fetch', url: 'http://thatapi.com/api2/thing'},
    {task: 'wait', duration: 60000 },
    ...
]

await Promise.each(arrayOfAsyncTasks, async(task) => {
  return handleTask(task)
})
```